# How to RegisterClassMap for all classes in a namespace for MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The [MongoDB driver tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Creatingaclassmap) suggests to register class maps to automap via

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>();
```

I would like to automap all classes of a given namespace without explicitly writing down RegisterClassMap for each class. Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need write `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>();`, because all classes will be automapped by default.

You should use `RegisterClassMap` when you need custom serialization:

```
 BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.SomeProperty));
    });
```

Also you can use attributes to create manage serialization(it's looks like more native for me):

```
[BsonId] // mark property as _id
[BsonElement("SomeAnotherName", Order = 1)] //set property name , order
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements] // ignore extra elements during deserialization
[BsonIgnore] // ignore property on insert
```

Also you can create global rules thats used during automapping, like this one:

```
var myConventions = new ConventionProfile();
myConventions.SetIdMemberConvention(new NoDefaultPropertyIdConvention());
BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(myConventions, t => true);
```

I am using only attributes and conventions to manage serialization process.

Hope this help.

Comment: As I found out, "all classes will be automapped by default" is stated in the tutorial/docs as well. Thanks Bugai13!

Comment: Be aware of `The one case where you must call RegisterClassMap yourself (even without arguments) is when you are using a polymorphic class hierarchy: in this case you must register all the known subclasses to guarantee that the discriminators get registered.` http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Creatingaclassmap

Comment: Reference link above to polymorphic class registration is broken - here's an [updated link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/class-mapping/#using-class-discriminators)

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the convention based registration, I needed to register class maps for a large number of `Type`s with some custom initialization code, and didn't want to repeat `RegisterClassMap<T>` for each type.

As per KCD's comment, if you do need to explicitly register class maps if you need to deserialize polymorphic class hierarchies, [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18846969/314291) [`BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3/html/1605728f-5c57-6889-d17f-912f73c4579a.htm) which will create a default AutoMapped registration for a given Type.

However, I needed to resort to this hack in order to perform custom map initialization steps, and unfortunately `LookupClassMap` freezes the map upon exit, which prevents further change to the returned `BsonClassMap`:

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);

var classMapDefinition = typeof(BsonClassMap<>);
var classMapType = classMapDefinition.MakeGenericType(type);
var classMap = (BsonClassMap)Activator.CreateInstance(classMapType);

// Do custom initialization here, e.g. classMap.SetDiscriminator, AutoMap etc

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
```

The code above is adapted from the `BsonClassMap LookupClassMap` implementation.