# Deserialising polymorphic types with MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver

Assume, I have a base class

```
public class Node{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public String nodeName;
    public ObjectId parentNode;
}
```

and 2 derived classes

```
public class PlotNode:Node{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public String plotDetail;
}

public class EndNode:Node{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public int resultCode;
}
```

Several objects of all 3 classes are serialized are in database.

And only data i have is a list of ObjectId's, and only thing known about these ids is that they are certain to be Node ids but it's not know whether they are Node,PlotNode or EndNode in deserialise time.

I am using this to deserialize:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Node>("nodes");
var query = Query<Node>.EQ(e => e.Id, id);
Node node = collection.FindOne(query);
```

And in the end i get Nodes, not actual PlotNodes or EndNodes.

How can i know if they are one of the derived types and get back a object of that type?

Comment: The only way I've achieved this is to use a custom serialiser and write the derived type to the BsonDocument during the serialise.  Then when you de-serialise you construct an object of the respective derived type.

Comment: That is one of the ways i figured it could be done, but i thought there would be an built-in way in the driver itself. I'll do it that way then, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck.  I write a `__t : { _type: '.net-type-string', _name: 'just the class name' }` when i serialise

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why do you have the same "public ObjectId Id;" in each derived class?
It is not really good idea. It hides parent Id field.

To solve your problem you need to "register" your derived classes (like in any serialization/deserialization mechanism).
    There are 3 ways to do it:

1. **Declarative way** - decorate base Node class with:

   ```
   [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(PlotNode), typeof(EndNode))]
   ```
2. **Generic way** - when types are known at compile time:

   ```
   BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<PlotNode>();
   BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EndNode>();
   ```
3. **Dynamic way** - when types are unknown at compile time:

   ```
   BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(PlotNode));
   BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(EndNode));
   ```

- *Another suggestion* - [use LINQ instead of Query](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)

  ```
  Node node = collection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
  ```

Comment: What effect would using `BsonClassMap.AddKnownType()` instead of `BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap()` cause?

Comment: AddKnownType(type) is an instance method in the BsonClassMap, meaning you would first need to create a BsonClassMap before calling that method. Not to mention, it will also register known types (hence the name). Whereas LookupClassMap(type) is a static method on BsonClassMap that has the side affect of creating a BsonClassMap instance, AutoMapping it, and registering it.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity: why do you suggest using LINQ instead of QUERY?