# MongoDB C# Driver Find not throwing System.FormatException Deserialization error and runs successfully

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using latest c# mongo driver in my .net core 2.0 app. I have this error in my code

**Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType 'Int64'.**.

But mongo query doesn't threw any exception. Here is the find method in my repository.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// find entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filter">expression filter</param>
        /// <returns>collection of entity</returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return Collection.Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// find entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filter">expression filter</param>
        /// <returns>collection of entity</returns>
        public Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => Find(filter));
        }
```

Here is the handler code

```
public async Task<object> Handle(GetQuestionBySurveyIdAndCodeQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      var result = await _context.Question.FindAsync(x => x.SurveyId.Equals(request.SurveyId));
      return result;
    }
```

Code run successfully but shows error inside data returned from this query.

[image]

[image]

I want to throw this exception so that my framework can handle it. Is their any settings related to this.

Need help.

Thanks

Comment: I know this doesn't address your question, but if the QuestionEntity.Variables property is polymorphic, you might be experiencing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642693/deserialising-polymorphic-types-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Comment: I want this exception to be thrown so that .net code framework can handle currently my api method run fine with as it should not be.

Comment: Does calling `result.ToList()` trigger it?  It looks like its a problem deserializing individual query results.   Calling ToList( ) should force the lazy enumerable to evaluate all results immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `FormatException` from MongoDB driver you need to **fetch** the data from the database while in your code you're only building a query. Extension method `.ToEnumerable()` you're using is not hitting the database so you won't get any results at that point. The documentation [says](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAsyncCursorExtensions_ToEnumerable__1.htm) that it:

> Wraps a cursor in an IEnumerable that can be enumerated one time.

So to enumerate a cursor you can for instance run `foreach` or `ToList` on it. Otherwise it's just a database query without any results. To fix that you can change your `Find` method body:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return Collection.Find(filter).ToList();
}
```

Comment: My other query are getting data from database using the same method

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan what I'm trying to say is that you will get the data using that method but it will not be enumerated inside your repo. Based on your post it will get enumerated: 1) when you expand `Results View` in debugger 2) When it gets serialized (`return Ok()`) which is not where you want to catch the exception I guess

Comment: Ok thanks it worked when I changed ToEnumerable to ToList().