# .Net MongoDB Deserialising prop based in an Interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, interface, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a couple classes tagged with an Interface. ex.:

```
public class Example1 : IExample {}

public class Example2 : IExample {}
```

On My master class, I have a prop of Example but declared as Interface. ex.:

```
public class Master
{
  public string Company { get; set; }

  public IExample Examples { get; set; }
}
```

To write to Mongo works fine, mongo adds a prop _t that have the name of the class signed by the interface, ex. Example1 or Example2

But to deserialise does not work at all. Throws an error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in MongoDB.Bson.dll: 'An error occurred while deserializing the Source property of class Audit.Processed: Unknown discriminator value 'Example1'.'
```

Do I have to register something or add some attribute of something to Mongo understands this class? Why the insert works?

I´ve found other posts like this one ([Deserialising polymorphic types with MongoDB C# Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642693/deserialising-polymorphic-types-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)), but all of them talk about base classes and not Interface as a property.

Worked as the checked post said, but I had to create a static class, other way would throw an exception saying that was registered allready. Here is the working code:

```
public class ClassMapRegisterer
{
    static ClassMapRegisterer()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Example1>();
    }

    public static void RegisterClassMaps()
    {            
    }
}
```

Before you open your connection, just use typing:

```
ClassMapRegisterer.RegisterClassMaps();
```

cheers

Comment: Can you show me the deserializer you're using? It helps to clarify the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/):

> If you ever see an error message about an “Unknown discriminator”, it is because the deserializer can’t figure out the class for that discriminator. If you are mapping your classes programmatically simply make sure that all classes in the hierarchy have been mapped before beginning deserialization.

You can't use the `BsonKnowTypes` attribute because it's restricted to classess and structs while you have an interface but you can use `RegisterClassMap`:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Example1>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Example2>();
```

Comment: Worked! But I had to create a static class an put the RegisterClassMap on it. Other way would throw an exception saying that the classMap was registered allready. Thanks.