# Mongodb C# array of different classes of objects for queries

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

I am attempting to have an array of similar objects inside of a mongodb document that are similar but still different.  I have tried using object[] but on the query it wants me to cast my class to a generic object.  Any ideas?

Object

```
public class BusinessService
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ServiceId { get; set; }
        public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public object[] Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

One of the different classes

```
public class Question1
   {
        [Required]
        public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        [BsonDefaultValue(null)]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public decimal? Increment { get; set; }
    }
```

The query

```
    {
        public async Task UpdateQuestion(Guid businessServiceId, Question1 serviceQuestion)
        {
            var filter = Builders<BusinessService>.Filter.Eq(bs => bs.BusinessServiceId, businessServiceId)
                & Builders<BusinessService>.Filter.ElemMatch(bs => bs.Questions, Builders<Question1>.Filter.Eq(q => q.QuestionId, serviceQuestion.QuestionId));
            var update = Builders<BusinessService>.Update.Set<Question1>(o => o.Questions[-1], serviceQuestion);
            await context.BusinessService.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
        }
```

Comment: You should use a common base class for your questions and have an array `public QuestioBase[] Questions { get; set; }` but see also this question which is probably what you are really asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642693/deserialising-polymorphic-types-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296277/deserializing-interface-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-unknown-discriminator-value

Comment: Ian. That was the solution.  Thank you!!