# MongoDB Serialization C# - Adding Additional Encrypted Field Properties

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write a MongoDb serializer in c# that will allow me to decorate properties via a **[Encrypt()]** attribute and then at runtime it would allow me to generate an additional property called **PropertyName_Encrypted** which would contain the encrypted value.

On deserialization, the encrypted property value would be set in the parent property so that the default GET for the property always returns the encrypted value. Users will then call an optional **Decrypt()** method on the object to get decrypted values.

In doing so, I'm running into some interesting challenges:

1. How do I add Additional properties to the document when I am serializing  current Element? How do I get the current element's name?
2. Is there a way I can read a specific property from the document/object? For e.g. say I want to pass a symmetric encryption key and read that to encrypt the data while serializing the current element? Is there any way I can do that?

Here are things I have done so far:

1. I've built an Encrypt Attribute as follows:

   ```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
     public class EncryptAttribute : Attribute
    {
    private readonly EncryptedFieldType _fieldType;
    private readonly bool _tokenizeDisplay;
    private readonly string _encryptedFieldName;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fieldType">The field type to encrypt. Useful if display needs to show some formatting. If no formatting is necessary, simply set to "Other".</param>
    /// <param name="tokenizeDisplay">If set to true, will persist the tokenized value in the original field for display purposes.</param>
    /// <param name="encryptedFieldName">Optional. If set, will save the encrypted value in the field name specified. By default all encrypted field values are stored in the corresponding _Encrypted field name. So EmailAddress field if encrypted, would have value under EmailAddress_Encrypted.</param>
    public EncryptAttribute(EncryptedFieldType fieldType, bool tokenizeDisplay, string encryptedFieldName = "")
    {
        _fieldType = fieldType;
        _tokenizeDisplay = tokenizeDisplay;
        _encryptedFieldName = encryptedFieldName;
    }
    }
   ```
2. I read this Attribute on Startup and add an Encryption Serializer to the properties that are decorated using this attribute. The code that does that is like so:

   ```
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("MongoCustomSerializer"))
            .ToList();
        var mapper = new Mapper();
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            mapper.Map(assembly);
        }
   ```
3. The mapper simply checks which properties in the document have the Encrypt attribute to add the serializer:

   ```
    public sealed class Mapper
    {
        public void Map(Assembly assembly)
        {
        var encryptableTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(p =>
            typeof(IEncryptable).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass && !p.IsInterface && !p.IsValueType &&
            !p.IsAbstract).ToList();

        if (encryptableTypes.Any())
        {
            foreach (var encryptableType in encryptableTypes)
            {
                Map(encryptableType);
            }
        }

    }

    private void Map(Type documentType)
    {
        var properties =
            documentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (properties.Length <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            RegisterEncrpytionSerializer(property, typeof(EncryptAttribute), documentType);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterEncrpytionSerializer(PropertyInfo property, Type encryptAttributeType, Type documentType)
    {
        var encryptAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(encryptAttributeType, false).ToList();
        if (!encryptAttributes.Any()) return;

        var memberMap = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(documentType).GetMemberMap(property.Name);
        memberMap?.SetSerializer(new EncryptionSerializer());
    }
   ```

   }

In my unit tests, I'm getting an error stating that the Bson Class Map is already frozen. Even if I were to figure out a way to bypass that, how would this EncryptionSerializer class work to where I could write an additional property?

Would love to see if someone can assist!

**UPDATE 1** - I was able to get the FREEZE error taken care of. It would appear that the LookupClassMap freezes the Member and Class Map info.

[This change from the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32330298/387014) allows me to take care of that issue:

```
private void RegisterEncrpytionSerializer(PropertyInfo property, Type encryptAttributeType, Type documentType)
    {
        var encryptAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(encryptAttributeType, false).ToList();
        if (!encryptAttributes.Any()) return;

        var classMapDefinition = typeof(BsonClassMap<>);
        var classMapType = classMapDefinition.MakeGenericType(documentType);
        var classMap = (BsonClassMap)Activator.CreateInstance(classMapType);
        classMap.AutoMap();
        var memberMap = classMap.GetMemberMap(property.Name);
        memberMap?.SetSerializer(new KeyVaultEncryptionSerializer(memberMap.ElementName));
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share what your EncryptionSerializer currently looks like?

Comment: Hello, my Encryption Serializer simply implements IBsonSerializer. I was never able to complete it because I needed to access another field to get the Key information. Let me re-write it again as much as I can to see if I can post a Gist.

Comment: Hello @marcofo88, here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/amarwadi/72e40954095f902d55b4ab7b9f61f183 you can see that my plan was to extract another property already available in the BSON document, and then use it to encrypt the current value. Problem is, there's no way to get any other properties from the BSON document.

Comment: Just an FYI that there are Ruby Gems that already do this. I wanted to build a pluggable component that anyone could use so long as they set the Master Key and the Content Encryption Key. https://www.compose.com/articles/encrypting-sensitive-data-in-your-mongodb-database/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a service for saving/retrieving your items that actually call the DB?

I believe you should move the responsibility for writing/reading encrypted values to the calling service (i.e a repository implementation) instead of the BsonSerializer.

It would make sense to me that encryption/decryption is part of the persistence layer and something not handled in the application when needed.

Your implementation targets only the specified property you want to serialize. It doesn't make sense that it creates another property.

A second thought is that your suggested approach with properties that change value based on `Decrypt()` probably isn't a good idea since it makes your code unpredictable and hard to read. Make your properties dead simple.

What extra security in your code does it really give you if you can decrypt properties by just calling a method anyway?

If you still need to have a `Decrypt()` would suggest that you create methods for decrypting that return the decrypted value like `GetUnencryptedCode()` etc, it could just as well be an extension method but still not a readable property.

You should also be looking into using `SecureString` depending on your use case.

Comment: Hello Jonas, I understand this. I finally ended up doing this manually. My goal was to automate this such that someone can simply add an IEncryptable interface to any object and then provide the Master Key Uri as well as a Content Encryption key (available via IEncryptable interface) and then simplify the saving process without the additional ceremony. And yes, I understand the decrypt process as well. My plan was to NOT decrypt by default i.e. put encrypted values in properties by default and require additional requests to decrypt. Automating encryption was the key.

Comment: Please also check my comment above, there are Ruby Gems that already do this and I was trying to replicate that in C#. https://www.compose.com/articles/encrypting-sensitive-data-in-your-mongodb-database/